# How to use bootstrap font using Unicode notation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I need a dropdown which will list border options using icons. To display icons I am using bootstrap library. Below is the code I am trying

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <option>
      &#xF1AD;
    </option>
  </select>
</body>
```

I got the Unicode from [Bootstrap docs](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/border-left/).  But icon is not rendering in the dropdown. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to also set the font family on those elements. In this case you need it on the options *and* the select element since it shows the selection. You'd have to then override for text options. The problem is that the selected value has the wrong font.

I'm not sure what your goal is, though. An option needs text to be accessible.

```css
.has-icons {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
}

.has-icons .other-font {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <select class="has-icons">
    <option>&#xF1AD;</option>
    <option class="other-font">Standard font option</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and it works. I got the similar response from Bootstrap team https://github.com/twbs/icons/issues/1266#issuecomment-1069625798 .
Please note that this solution doesn't work in Firefox as it doesn't support styling of <option> element